# CASE WHEN NOT doesn't produce the right results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently working with the titanic.sql dataset, 
and one question I need to answer is calculating the odds of survivals of females in the second class.

(I do beleive calculating odds is #where case is true/ #where case not true)

I have two different sql statements which produce different results.
I am assuming that CASE WHEN NOT doesn't work...

I might not be understanding the logic but can someone explain?

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN sex='female' AND class='2nd' AND survived=1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / 
      CAST(
        SUM(CASE WHEN NOT sex='female' AND NOT class='2nd' AND NOT survived=1 
            THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) 
    AS FLOAT) 
AS odds_second_fem_surive FROM passengers; 



SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN sex='female' AND class='2nd' AND survived=1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / 
      CAST( COUNT(*) - (CASE WHEN sex='female' AND class='2nd' AND survived=1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)
    AS FLOAT) 
AS odds_second_fem_surive____ FROM passengers;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some knowledge of boolean logic.

The negative of:

```
sex = 'female' AND class = '2nd'
```

Is:

```
not (sex = 'female' AND class = '2nd')
```

This is also expressed in either of these two equivalent ways:

```
not sex = 'female' or not class = '2nd'
sex <> 'female' or not class <> '2nd'
```

This is not the same as:

```
not sex = 'female' and not class = '2nd'
```

Note:  these expressions are slightly more complicated if the columns can be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
CASE WHEN NOT sex='female' AND NOT class='2nd' AND NOT survived=1
```

negates all conditions individually. While what you want is negate them together, so if any of conditions don't match, whole thing does not match. Thus:

```
CASE WHEN NOT (sex='female' AND class='2nd' NOT survived=1)
```

That should make it match the second query results.